# Hashing paswords on client or on server.Whats better

Tags: security, networking, hash

I would like to ask(as my title says) if its better practice to hash passwords using sha256 on client side and send it over ssl or send plain text over ssl and hash it on server side.I guess there should be no difference right ?
What do you pro´s do ?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8596/https-security-should-password-be-hashed-server-side-or-client-side

Comment: Oh how could I miss that one :( Thank you very much.